# how can I let my function work repeatedly infinitely

Tags: javascript, algorithm

here is my pseudo code

```
var list = {
    a:[
        {content: 'a', time: 5},
        {content: 'b', time:2}, 
        {content: 'c', time:3}]
    }

var insert_and_stop = function(content, time){
    //let content insert to somewhere and wait for "time" second
}
```

my requirement is running a loop to insertSome(content, time) on dataset(list)
and start over again to the head of list
obviously, I can use `for` to run my function on list

but I don't know how to start over?

### Sorry for incomplete code

### Update !!!

my solution right now is:

```
for(var i = 0; i<list.a.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(insert(list.a[i].content), list.a[i].time * 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

it works but i don't if I let `while(true)` include this code
the browser will crash because the `for...` part will run repeatly

Comment: Have you tried using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code as a reference and your query, here is how I would approach it:

```
var list = {
    a:[
        {content: 'a', time: 5},
        {content: 'b', time:2}, 
        {content: 'c', time:3}]
    }
var i = 0;
var insertContent = function(){
    // Do something with the content
    console.log(list.a[i].content);

    // Either increment the i or restart at 0.
    if((list.a.length - 1) > i ){
        i++;
    }else{
        i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        // Run the function again
        insertContent();
    }, list.a[i].time * 1000);
}
```

This code will loop until the end of the array and then starts again.

I have tested it on my side and seems to be working, however I did rename the function, so just adapt it according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I think what `pid` meant to say in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902599/how-can-i-let-my-function-work-repeatedly-infinitely/34902631#34902631) is that you should use:
[`setInterval(function, delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)
Where `function` is the function name and `delay` is the delay in milliseconds between invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval(<function-name>, <delay-in-milliseconds>)` where `<function-name>` is the *function name* or a lambda (if you know what this is) and `<delay-in-milliseconds>` is the *delay in milliseconds* between invocations.

Otherwise, if you actually need to do it inside `insert_and_stop()` you can do as follows. Write an actual *function* (this means you need just **1 exit point**). Then, just before you exit your function:

```
setTimeout(function () { insert_and_stop(content, time); }, time);
```

You need the lambda (the wrapping function) because the parameters `content` and `time` need to be passed correctly for the subsequent invocations.

Note that this will not invoke your function every `<time>` milliseconds because the execution time of the function itself is not accounted for. If `insert_and_stop()` takes a time that is similar to `<time>` this effect might become sensible. Otherwise, if the function is quick (microseconds) and the interval is high (100 or 1000 times as long) then the overhead may be negligible, based on what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

The two options here are `setInterval(function, delay)` and `setTimeout(function, delay)`. The main difference being, that `setInterval` will fire exactly each `delay` time period, while `setTimeout` will only fire when the internal code has been run. In practice, you would have to look out for side effects in case of code that runs for longer than you'd expect (and that would cause `setInterval` to stack the code on top of itself multiple times).

Examples:

```
function myTimeoutFunc(){
  // .. some code
  setTimeout(myFunc, delay-in-milliseconds);
}
myFunc();


function myIntervalFunc(){
  // .. some code
}
setInterval(myIntervalFunc, delay-in-milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//set my function each 3seconds
var interval = setInterval("myFunction", 3000);
//or
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    alert("I am myFunction");
}, 3000);

//release
releaseInterval(interval);
```

It's important "setInterval" return value that needs to release!